# Transform shapefile polygon for a better search in C

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, polygon, shapefile

I am currently working on shapefile and I've some problems. I need to know if I am inside a polygon but when calling the functions, it need to be fast (the answer need to found in less than 20 ms). Everything I do is on arm-architecture, with 1 FPU@1GHz

Do I need to transform my shapefile in something with a better spatial organization (like a tree) ? What kind of data structure would you recommend ?

Comment: A single polygon? Concave, complex? There is a simple and dummy algorithm for calculating whether something is inside a complex - whether or not it can work itself out in 20ms depends on the number of vertices...

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Multiple polygons and all have irregular shape, and also a various number of points (but in general no less than 50~100, with no limit)

Comment: so if there are multiple 2d polygons, then google for quadtree.

Comment: Show your present code. Also, say if there's something you know about the polygons that might help. For instance, this problem becomes much simpler if you can assume that they are convex.

Comment: *"I need to know if I am inside a polygon"* — Do you need to find out whether a point lies inside a polygon? Or another polygon?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thx for your answer I did some research and I found the PM quadtree. I will use PM1

Comment: @klutt the polygon has all unknow form. I will post some code as soon as I fully understand pm quadtree

Comment: @user3290797 I understood how to make pm quadtree, but I did not understand how to search if a point is inside a polygon. if you have a point, do I need to search in all neighborhood and find all q-edges and vertices to confirm that I am inside a polygon? I am a little confused.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: @MichaelVouriz See also: [Point in Polygon Strategies](http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/). I'd suggest starting from the Bins Method.

Comment: i ditched the quadtree and directly use jordan method. Guess i was doing something too complicated for something so simple (still a student). Well, now i know how tree work. Thx everyone